# WM_HOTKEY not catching

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am trying to assign a hotkey for my MFC application. I want it to work even when my application is not in focus.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

My dialog inherits the `CWnd` class, as such:

`class CMyClass : public CWnd`

In the class, I defined this:

```
protected:
//...
afx_msg void OnHotKey(UINT id, UINT key1, UINT key2);
```

EDIT: I also tried putting the `override` keyword there, but then it tells me that it does not inherit a base-class member.

In my implementation:

```
void CMyClass::OnHotKey(UINT id, UINT key1, UINT key2)
{
    if (id == 1 || id == 2)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In my constructor:

```
if (!RegisterHotKey(NULL /* also tried m_hWnd */, 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT, 0x56 /* 'V' */))
{
  // do some failure code, but it passes
}
if (!RegisterHotKey(NULL /* also tried m_hWnd */, 2, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT, 0x76 /* 'v' */))
{
  // do some failure code.. but it passes
}
```

In my destructor:

```
// Unregister hotkeys
UnregisterHotKey(NULL /* also tried m_hWnd */, 1);
UnregisterHotKey(NULL /* also tried m_hWnd */, 2);
```

And in my `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`:

```
ON_WM_HOTKEY()
```

Now I debugged it, even when I press SHIFT+ALT+'v', it does not get into the `OnHotKey` function.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem?

Comment: You've mentioned Ctrl-Alt-V but programmed Alt-Shit-V as hot key. I guess its just typo?

Comment: Yes. Just a typo. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering your hot keys in constructor when **window handle is not initialized yet**.

You should initialize your hot keys in `OnCreate()` just like this:

```
::RegisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT, 'V');
::RegisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), 2, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT, 'v');
```

The unregister part should be done in `OnDestroy()`:

```
::UnregisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), 1);
::UnregisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), 2);
```